# Gtk Perl: Programmatically adding an item to a Gtk2::ComboBox

Tags: perl, gtk

While working with Gtk and Perl, I have to programmatically add an option to a ComboBox.

```
if($self->Entry()->get_text() ne "")
{
    $self->ComboBox1()->append_text($self->Entry()->get_text());
}
```

This works, but the entry added is not available the next time the GUI is run. How can the GUI be updated?

Comment: I don't understand the question. You're asking about adding an entry to a combobox, but your code is adding an item to the combobox's item list? And are you saying the combobox item isn't surviving? Are there any warnings on stderr? What's the backing model? Is this a GtkComboBoxText?

Comment: I used the word "entry" inadvertently. Yes, I'm saying the added item isn't surviving. There are no warnings on stderr. This is a `Gtk2::ComboBox`.

Comment: And what do you mean by "next time GUI is run"?

Comment: I'm going to assume you meant you want the items to be available the next time you run your program. **If so:** GTK+ does not provide that functionality; it just provides widgets for you to use to make programs with. You will have to do that yourself; sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write the added item to a configuration file. Then, read the file every time the GUI starts up and re-add all the items from previous runs.